# Adding text to the top or side of a picture, then using css to customize it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hello people of stack overflow. I have a picture on my website and i was wondering how i can enter text to the side of the photo. How would i then use css to customize the text font and color ext. If this is possible how would i also put text on the top of a picture? Right now i am using bootstrap, so my picture is in a specific "row". I will add the link to my test website if you are wondering what i mean by that.

My website: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Regards.

Comment: Please, show us what you've tried!

Comment: are you asking how to do this using twitter bootstrap or do you just in general?

Comment: I guess bootstrap but if their is a general way of doing this that would be awesome to know.

Comment: Honestly this is so basic, you should probably just learn some basic html/css. See `background-image` or `position: absolute` for starters. Both viable places to start.

Comment: This is what i have tried but the font is not changing to ariel.  <p style="margin-left: 650px; margin-top: -355px;" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random Random vRandom Random Random Random Random Random </p>

Comment: You can only have one style attribute per tag, so only the first style was rendering. Put all the styles in one attribute like:`<p style="margin-left: 650px; margin-top: -355px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">`

Comment: @user3905042 Also, can you add the code (from your comment) to the question? That way, the problem is easier to address.